# access windows 7 Libraries with Powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, libraries

do you know some way to navigate trough windows libraries in Powershell?, exist some provider? it will be nice have this posibility because in libraries i have everything that i need almost in one ore two dir depth when in reality practically all those dirs are four or five+ dir depth

Answer (score 2):

I created a library for this for my own use. It is posted here:
http://blog.crayon.no/blogs/ragnar/archive/2009/09/02/scripting-windows-7-libraries.aspx

-Ragnar

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use the .net framework, take a look at [Windows 7 Taskbar and Libraries .NET Interop Sample Library](http://javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$Content$TabContentPanel$Content$ReleaseFiles$FileList$ctl00$FileNameLink',''))